# Docker port binding doesn't seem to work

Tags: macos, docker

I am running an example from Docker tutorial:

```
docker run -d -P nginx
```

This starts correctly as `docker ps` outputs the following:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                           NAMES
a5838f701c8f   nginx   "nginx -g 'daemon off"   3 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:32773->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32772->443/tcp   compassionate_stallman
```

When I run `docker inspect a5838f701c8f`, I can see the IP of the container is `172.17.0.2`.
However, for some reason going to `localhost:32772` or `127.0.0.1:32772` or `0.0.0.0:32772` gives me `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. Going to `172.17.0.2:32772` just seems to endlessly load and load and never loads anything...
Could this be something with my host? I am using OSX 10.9.5 and docker 1.10.3, build 20f81dd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should test with URL `192.168.99.104:32772` If you are using Docker Machine.

Please take a look with https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/ip/ to know how to get IP address with Docker Machine

Comment: Indeed I was supposed to use Docker Machine IP. Thanks.